# Can't get login script to work after adding salt to hash; worked fine before

Tags: php, mysql, database, hash, salt

I've reset my database and on registration, we added random salt to hashes, and the registration script worked fine, we could create accounts and accounts with the same password and they had different hashes, but our login script is broken, not logging in users, saying their password is incorrect.

No idea why- we have spent the last 2 hours trying to fix it. We have used PHP error checkers(https://phpcodechecker.com/), nothing was wrong.

We are running an old version PHP(5.6) and MySQL and can't currently change.

```
    <?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require_once 'dbconnect.php';

    // it will never let you open index(login) page if session is set
    if ( isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ) {
     header("Location: index.php");
     exit;
    }

    $error = false;

    if( isset($_POST['btn-login']) ) { 

     // prevent sql injections/ clear user invalid inputs
     $email = trim($_POST['email']);
     $email = strip_tags($email);
     $email = htmlspecialchars($email);

     $name = trim($_POST['name']);
     $name = strip_tags($name);
     $name = htmlspecialchars($name);


     $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
     $pass = strip_tags($pass);
     $pass = htmlspecialchars($pass);
     // prevent sql injections / clear user invalid inputs

     if(empty($name)){
      $error = true;
      $nameError = "Please enter your username.";
     }

     if(empty($pass)){
      $error = true;
      $passError = "Please enter your password.";
     }
       $res=mysql_query("SELECT userId, userEmail, userPass, userSalt, userSalt2 FROM users WHERE userName='$name'");
      $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);



      $row['userSalt']=$salt1;
      $row['userSalt2']=$salt2;
     // if there's no error, continue to login
     if (!$error) {

        $passwordHash = hash('sha256', $salt1 . $password . $salt2); // password hashing using SHA256

      //$res=mysql_query("SELECT userId, userEmail, userPass, userSalt,        userSalt2 FROM users WHERE userName='$name'");
      //$row=mysql_fetch_array($res); 
      $count = mysql_num_rows($res); // if email/pass correct it returns must be 1        row

      if( $count == 1 && $row['userPass']==$passwordHash ) {
       $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userId'];
header("Location: dashboard.php");
      } else {
       $errMSG = "Incorrect Credentials, Try again...";
      }

     }

    }
   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(function(){
        $("#overallhead").load("overall_header.php"); 
        $("#overallfoot").load("overall_footer.html"); 
    });
   </script>
   <style>
   body {
    color: Thistle;
    }
    </style>
   <div id="overallhead"></div>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Creature Paradise</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"  />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <body>

   <div class="container">

    <div id="login-form">
       <form method="post" action="<?php echo        htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" autocomplete="off">

 <div class="col-md-12">

     <div class="form-group">
         <h2 class="">Login</h2>
        </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <hr />
         </div>

        <?php
      if ( isset($errMSG) ) {

       ?>
       <div class="form-group">
         <div class="alert alert-danger">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <?php echo $errMSG; ?>
            </div>
         </div>
            <?php
      }
      ?> 

        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
         <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Username" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" maxlength="40" />
            </div>
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $nameError; ?></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
         <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Password" maxlength="15" />
            </div>
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $passError; ?></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <hr />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="btn-login">Sign In</button>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <hr />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                <a href="register.php">Don't have an account? Sign up here!              </a>
               </div>

           </div>

       </form>
       </div> 

   </div>
   <div id="overallfoot"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
   <?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: A lot of code: Reduce to the relevant part please

Comment: None of the functions you are using would stop a SQL injections and you are changing the actual password value with those functions. Is `username` also unique? Additionally 5.6 supports `mysqli`, `pdo` and `password_hash`/`password_verify`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you do hashing on registration page, too? Because `$row['userPass']` will never equal `$passwordHash` if you have not registration a new account with new hash applied